# Create-react-app installed but npm WARN deprecated

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm just a beginner to react and when i try `npx create-react-app my-app` and then `npm install`, it gives me a this message

```
added 1481 packages, and audited 1487 packages in 4m

253 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

When i run `npm  audit` this is the output:

```
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          node_modules/react-scripts

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

And the last time i used the `npm audit fix --force` that

> 8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

Became

> 138 vulnerabilities (... moderate,  ... high, 4 Critical)

And then they wasn't just warnings anymore, because before that i could use the `npm start` but then even that Was showing me error with `package.json` file.

I was just trying to learn react, that wasn't an important project for me so i deleted it, but what should i do in the next react app using `create-react-app`?

And one more thing, i have created another project using vite before it didn't have this problems but now i need to do that using `create-react-app`. Thanks

Comment: Most `npm audit` issues won't affect your app. You really shouldn't be using CRA, though - Vite is better.

Comment: Yes, you're right and and I am using CRA just because i wanted to test (and learn) working with both.